# Multiple conditions for IF NOT EMPTY

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

If I use `%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@type_dsc3) AND (@p_price3) THEN]%%` it won't check if p_price3 is empty.

If I use `%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@type_dsc3 AND @p_price3) THEN]%%` I get an error

Help, I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 6):

Should be:

```
%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@type_dsc3) AND NOT EMPTY(@p_price3) THEN]%%
```

Comment: How to declare !=(Is Not equal to) in Lookuprows. Here Stat attribute value is 3 but i want show !=3 values. LookupRows("MyDE","Status",@Stat)